# Google parsing spreadsheet of URLS and changing characters

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have the following URL added to my google shopping feed:

```
https://www.testwebsite.com/product_info.php?products_id=487{5}102{3}289&currency=USD
```

When Google is parsing it into merchant center it changes the curly bracket characters to the following:

```
https://www.testwebsite.com/product_info.php?products_id=487%7B5%7D102%7B3%7D289&currency=USD
```

It is important that the URLs link directly to the variant and the way Google is changing the URL is causing the website not to recognize the URL. What can I do?

Comment: Not an answer, but it's probably a bug in your application if `{` and `%7B` are not considered the same thing. Very surprising for a PHP application, because they should do this automatically unless they wrote their own url parser.

Comment: Thanks kind of helped. There is a custom URL rewrite addon that was/is causing the problem. If I disable the redirect that is automatically caused then the URL works as it is supposed to. I might repost this question with the rewrite rule that is in htaccess.